# Jquery event handler not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that is having some javascript issues. I have tried looking over everything however I have a username field and when you click it (`.focus`) it should bring up a pop up. I used firebug in firefox to put break points right then the `.focus` function is called and it it is not fired even though I do focus on the username field. I have also looked over spelling and everything. Cant seem to find the issue. Hope someone can help. One more thing, this issue is happening in all browsers.

page link: http://aliahealthcareer.com/SignUp

Comment: In order to be more clear, you could specify which element (id?) you are having issues with

Comment: `$('#username')` is what your looking for

Comment: I'm seeing all your script files and css coming as as a webpage

Comment: what do you mean are coming as a webpage?

Comment: see http://aliahealthcareer.com/ajax_framework.js

Comment: that is an ajax call that has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page has two inputs with `id="username"`.

Repeating ids is invalid html, but the browser kind of ignores it except that `$('#username')` finds only the first one so your `.focus()` handler is bound to that one.

The first is within the "login_response" div that is hidden until you click the "Login" option, so if you click "Login" and then click the "Username/Email" field that appears you'll see that your event handler runs.

Comment: Yes I just saw that and came back here to post that. I have racked my brain all day and it was soemthing that simple, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You have JS issues on load of that page. JS wont work properly thereafter. You need to fix those first.

Comment: I don't think you could be more ambiguous and less helpful if you tried.  Clarify with additional details to regain the -1 I gave you.

Comment: I just tried to point him in  the right direction. He has OTHER javascript issues on his page (onload) that is preventing his objective. ( JS stops when it encounters errors)

Comment: I had posted a sample of what the actual problems were and the errors in PHP while trying to fetch the javascript files.  I deleted my post due to relevance now that someone else posed a solution that worked.  I'll undelete my post so you can see how you should explain errors like this to a OP.

Comment: no problem dude, going to delete it again. Happy answering :-)